# java.io.NotSerializableException:org.saiku.datasources.connection.SaikuOlapConnection

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, deserialization, saiku

I deployed the two files ( saiku.war  and saiku-ui.war  version 2.5) in  tomcat server  :
I'm getting "java.io.NotSerializableException:org.saiku.datasources.connection.SaikuOlapConnection"

below the error message generated

please help.

Thank you in advance

GRAVE: "IOException" loading persistent sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.saiku.datasources.connection.SaikuOlapConnection
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.saiku.datasources.connection.SaikuOlapConnection
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1852)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1756)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1326)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1950)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1874)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1756)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1326)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1950)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1874)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1756)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1326)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1950)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1874)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1756)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1326)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1950)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1874)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1756)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1326)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1509)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:998)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:446)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4631)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Answer (score 0):

### TL; DR: You need to disable HTTP [session persistence](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts).

You have objects of class `org.saiku.datasources.connection.SaikuOlapConnection` stored in the HTTP session, which don't `implements Serializable`. Tomcat will automatically attempt to save HTTP session to disk on shutdown so that they can be resumed on start.

You can see this from the stacktrace:

```
SNIP
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348) at 
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1509) at 
SNIP
```

In order to disable this feature, you simply need to follow the instructions in [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence):

> As documented above, every web application by default has standard
>   manager implementation configured, and it performs session persistence
>   across restarts. To disable this persistence feature, create a Context
>   configuration file for your web application and add the following
>   element there:
>
> `<Manager pathname="" />`